# Making a switch-heavy function more reusable

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, reusability

Suppose I have this code:

```
void ClassA::SomeFunction()
{
    switch(something)
    {
    case case1:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case case2:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
       .
       . 
       .
}
...
void ClassB::SomeFunction()
{
    switch(something) // this 'something' is the same 'something' as in
    {                 // the above class
    case case1:
        doSomethingCompletelyUnrelatedToClassAFunction();
        break;
    case case2:
        doSomethingCompletelyUnrelatedToClassAOtherFunction();
        break;
       .
       . 
       .
}
```

The two functions in two classes do fairly different things under the exact same cases (all cases within both switches are exactly the same).
Basically I'm writing a small Chip-8 emulator for fun and the two classes represent my "CPU" and disassembler.

The CPU should decode the opcode and do some stuff while the disassembler should simply format a string based on the opcode.

I'm trying to think of a way to avoid copy/pasting the entire switch and just changing the functions called in each case.

One simple solution I've come up with is make an abstract class which handles an opcode and has a different method for each of the cases in the switch. Both the CPU and the Disassembler classes would extend this class and implement their own behavior for each of the methods. However I'm hoping for a more elegant solution than that.

Thanks.

EDIT:

As per @Dogbert 's comment I'm adding a chunk of actual code:

```
wxString* DebugWindow::DisassembleOpCode(uint16_t opCode)
{
wxString disLine;

uint8_t nibble1 = (opCode & 0xF000) >> 12;
uint8_t nibble2 = (opCode & 0x0F00) >> 8;
uint8_t nibble3 = (opCode & 0x00F0) >> 4;
uint8_t nibble4 = (opCode & 0x000F);

if (opCode == 0x00E0)
    disLine = "CLS";
else if (opCode == 0x00EE)
    disLine = "RET";
else
    switch (nibble1)
{
    case 0x1:
    {
                // JMP nnn
                disLine = wxString::Format("JMP %04x", nibble2 | nibble3 | nibble4);
                break;
    }
    case 0x2:
    {
                // CALL nnn
                disLine = wxString::Format("CALL %04x", nibble2 | nibble3 | nibble4);
                break;
    }
    case 0x3:
    {
                // SE V[x], nn  -- skip next instruction if V[x] == nn
                disLine = wxString::Format("SE V[%x], %02x", nibble2, nibble3 | nibble4);
                break;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    case 0x8: // arithmetic operations between registers, see below
        {
                      switch (nibble4)
                      {
                      case 0x0:
                      {
                                  // LD V[x], V[y] -- sets value of register V[x] to value of register V[y]
                                  disLine = wxString::Format("ADD V[%x], V[%x]", nibble2, nibble3);
                                  break;
                      }
                      case 0x1:
                      {
                                  // OR V[x], V[y] -- performs bitwise OR of values of registers V[x] and V[y], the result is stored in V[x]
                                  disLine = wxString::Format("OR V[%x], V[%x]", nibble2, nibble3);
                                  break;
                      }

     ...
     ...
```

This is a part of DisassembleOpcode function. The Step function in the CPU class should actually do stuff instead of formatting a string but is consisted of the same switch/cases.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the `something` you are switching on and the sample cases? If you only have a single function call per `case` statement, you you possibly even replace the `switch` statement with a 2D array of `int`s and function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same vein as dasblinkenlight suggested, I would even say that "tabulizing" the instruction-set would greatly enhance the readability of the design. Something along the lines of:

```
struct opcode instructionset[] = {
{ 0x1000, "JMP %04x", &do_jump},
...
```

Your code would then access the table for each instruction, probably the table would be sorted by opcode for quick lookup:

```
struct opcode op* = find(opCode, instructionset);
// for printing the instruction
disLine = wxString::Format(op->formatstring, opCode & op->format_mask);
```

You get the idea... But the key point is: You would have a nicely formatted table of your implemented instructionset, which I think would greatly ease maintenance / future addition of instructions.

Answer (score 4):

In C, you can replace a switch with an array of function pointers. In C++ you have an additional option of using pointers to a class with polymorphic behavior.

Here is how you can do it with function pointers:

```
typedef void (*disassembly_action)(uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t);

static void doSomethingOpcodeZero(uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t);
static void doSomethingOpcodeOne(uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t);
static void doSomethingOpcodeTwo(uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t,uint8_t);
static disassembly_action disassembly[] = {
    doSomethingOpcodeZero
,   doSomethingOpcodeOne
,   doSomethingOpcodeTwo
,   ...
};
```

Now you can use an array indexing instead of a switch:

```
void ClassA::SomeFunction() {
    uint8_t nibble1 = (opCode & 0xF000) >> 12;
    uint8_t nibble2 = (opCode & 0x0F00) >> 8;
    uint8_t nibble3 = (opCode & 0x00F0) >> 4;
    uint8_t nibble4 = (opCode & 0x000F);
    disassembly_action[something](nibble1, nibble2, nibble3, nibble4);
}
```

You can build a similar array to replace the other `switch`, perhaps using a different signature for your `action` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick approach with a kind of EventHandler for something that you can register at a Router that receives something:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class SomethingHandler
{
public: 
    SomethingHandler() {}
    ~SomethingHandler() {}

    virtual void handleSomething(int something)
    {
        doHandleSomething(something);
    }

private:
    virtual void doHandleSomething(int something) = 0;

};

class Router
{
public:
    Router() {}

    void registerHandlerForSomething(int somethingInteresting, SomethingHandler* h)
    {
        m_handler.push_back(std::pair<int,SomethingHandler*> (somethingInteresting, h));
    }

    void receive(int something) const
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < m_handler.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(m_handler.at(i).first == something)
            {
                if(m_handler.at(i).second)
                {
                    m_handler.at(i).second->handleSomething(something);
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector< std::pair<int,SomethingHandler*> > m_handler;
};

class aHandler : public SomethingHandler
{
public:
    aHandler() {}
private:
    void doHandleSomething(int something) 
    {
        std::cout << "handled something: " << something << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Router r;
    aHandler h;

    r.registerHandlerForSomething(42, &h);

    r.receive(42);
}
```

this should give the following output:

```
g++ main.cpp; ./a.out
handled something: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You could invent a domain specific language for describing parallel switch statements and then transform it into independent switch statements with a perl script invoked from the Makefile.

For instance:

```
BEGIN CASE 0x1
    BEGIN FACET disassemble
        // disassemble code for 0x1 goes here
    END FACET
    BEGIN FACET execute
        // execute code goes for 0x1 here
    END FACET
END CASE
BEGIN CASE 0x2
    BEGIN FACET disassemble
        // disassemble code for 0x2 goes here
    END FACET
    BEGIN FACET execute
        // execute code for 0x2 goes here
    END FACET
END CASE
```

A perl script can easily tease apart the facets into separate files:

*disassemble.cc*

```
case 0x1:
    // disassemble code for 0x1 goes here
    break;
case 0x2:
    // disassemble code for 0x2 goes here
    break;
```

*execute.cc*

```
case 0x1:
    // execute code for 0x1 goes here
    break;
case 0x2:
    // execute code for 0x2 goes here
    break;
```

You can then `#include` the cases into the appropriate switch contexts.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

our %bindings;
our $case;
our $binding;

while(<>) {
    if(/^\s*BEGIN CASE (.*)$/) {
        die "Unexpected BEGIN CASE" if defined $case;
        $case = $1;
    }
    elsif(/^\s*END CASE$/) {
        die "Unexpected END CASE" if !defined $case or $binding;
        undef $case;
    }
    elsif(/^\s*BEGIN FACET (.*)$/) {
        die "Unexpected BEGIN FACET" if !defined $case or $binding;
        $binding = {case => $case, code => []};
        push @{$bindings{$1}}, $binding;
    }
    elsif(/^\s*END FACET$/) {
        die "Unexpected END FACET" unless $binding;
        undef $binding;
    }
    elsif($binding) {
        push @{$binding->{code}}, $_;
    }
}

for my $facet (sort keys %bindings) {
    print "#ifdef FACET_", uc($facet), "\n";
    for my $binding (@{$bindings{$facet}}) {
        print "case ", $binding->{case}, ":\n";
        print $_ for (@{$binding->{code}});
        print "break;\n";
    }
    print "#endif\n";
}
```